# adding values to the next row of matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix (5,5) #empty matrix
I want to add elements row-wise.

how to code to add elements to the next row if the previous row is full.

the first row is full and I want to add more elements but from the next row automatically

Comment: Read [mcve] and [tour] then edit your post accordingly. Your post missing some must needed details.

Comment: Please do not reuse a question to ask something else by editing it after the original question has been answered. Rolled back to the last version of the original question.

Comment: sorry, I'm new to stack overflow. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: You can just ask a new question if you'd like @PrashantRavulakolu

Comment: Yes, I marked it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be what you are after:

```
outer_matrix = [[None]*5 for i in range(5)]


def auto_add(element, matrix):
    for row in range(len(matrix)):
        for col in range(len(matrix[row])):
            if matrix[row][col] == None:
                # There is a free space, add element to it
                matrix[row][col] = element
                return matrix


for i in range(12):
    outer_matrix = auto_add(i, outer_matrix)
```

```
>>> outer_matrix
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [10, 11, None, None, None],
 [None, None, None, None, None],
 [None, None, None, None, None]]
```

---

If you are always using a `5 x 5` matrix, this is cleaner:

```
for row in range(5):
    for col in range(5):
```